# Sphere, Analytical geometry

Tags: 3d, spheres

***show that if all the plane sections of a surface, which has equation of second degree, are circles,the surface must be a sphere.***

I have uploaded one image,[just click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nPk5.jpg).Please check whether this is correct or not as in question it is asked in general second degree equation but i have assume simply sphere. If not right, then please provide answer.

[image]

Comment: Why did you assume that $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x,y,z)$ are ortogonal?

Comment: As plane sections of surface are circle and i have assumed (x1, y1,z1) are centre of the circle.

Comment: Seems that you are assuming that $(0,0,0)$ is already a center of a sphere.

Comment: I think your solution is not right.

Comment: yes i am assumed (0,0,0) centre of sphere for simplicity. One thing is wrongly written in above image that is it should be ** equation of plane passing through $(x_1, y_1,z_1)$ and having direction ratios $x_1, y_1, z_1$ is:  ** $x_1(x-x_1)+y_1(y-y_1)+z_1(z-z_1)$=0.